# Google map fragment or google map activty

Tags: android, dictionary, android-activity, fragment

Namaste friends, I am creating a custom app that uses google map. My first activity is splash screen. I have also created a navigation drawer and in which I want to put a google map. So should I create a google map activity or a fragment ? If I create an activity then which activity should I call from splash screen ?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to solve your case. You can load google map into `MainActivity` and after `SplashScreen` open `MainActivity`.

Second scenario - You can open MainActivity after `SplashScreen` and in `MainActivity` load `GoogleMapFragment` into `Activity` container.And with navigation drawer you can set options to open other fragments and of course your `GoogleMapFragment`.

Of course there are many other ways to do this, just give you idea from which you can start to coding!